# Remove \" in C# string

Tags: c#, string

I need to remove all instances of  `\"` in a string.  But I don't want to remove all `\` and `"`, only `\"`

```
<div class=\"foo\">
```

to this:

```
<div class="foo">
```

**Future Readers:**

Although this post is closed, please read:

Be sure that the string really contains a `\"`.   It may just be your debugger adding the characters like in my case.  In which case you can ignore them.

Otherwise, please see the recommended Stackoverflow post above.

Comment: Are you sure there are any? You're probably looking at the escaped form of the string eg in a debugger watch or popup

Comment: How *exactly* are you observing the `\"` in the first place? In my experience, most questions that talk about this are due to someone looking in the debugger, which performs escaping - the backslashes aren't actually there.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking in visual studio debugger when I see this

Comment: @KidBilly then there are no backslashes at all. The debugger displays special characters in their escaped form.

Comment: Right. In which case, the strings probably don't have any backslashes. Try printing them to the console, or writing them to a file etc.

Comment: Well thanks you guys.  haha Post updated

Comment: `It's only in VS Code debugger.` Visual Studio, Rider, probably all IDEs and browser developer tools do this as well. Otherwise there's no way to display a newline or tab

Comment: By `it's only in VS Code debugger` I referring to my specific case.  Not trying to imply that this is a feature of only VS Code debugger

Answer (score 1):

Since " is a special character, you need to have \ before it in a string.

when you print

```
<div class=\"foo\">
```

to IO, I believe you will see

```
<div class="foo">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ctrl+h` from `\"` to `"`

Or `String.Replace([string], [string])`  from `\"` to `"`

Comment: That's assuming this is a file in the editor - I see no indication of that, particularly given that the OP wrote "in a string".

Comment: That would try to replace something that doesn't exist. `\"` is how the debugger displays double quotes. All special characters are displayed in their escaped form